# Flex mobile - click to make phone call or send an email, on iOS

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe

Can I make a button, that when I click it the phone makes a call to a certain number, or similarly sends an email to certain address with some pre-populated fields. I need this to work on iOS and Android too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make a URL request actually that the phone understands to make a call. You just prefix it with tel. Same works for "mailto".

See this example: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_uris.html

Answer (score 1):

see this the exact thing you all looking for

http://www.flextechie.com/my-first-flex-mobile-application-contact-mobile-app/

you can even download the source code

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code on Button Click :

-(void) makeCall
    {

```
NSString * mobileNumber = @"+9112345678";

UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",mobileNumber]]];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *Notpermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Your device doesn't support calling feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [Notpermitted show];
    }
}
```